# How to include custom metadata fields in a request for folder items?

Tags: c#, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am integrating Box functionality in my Winforms application. I am able to add and retrieve custom metadata tags to and for a file on Box. When I fetch the items in a Box folder I do not get the custom metadata fields that I added. How can I include these custom metadata fields with the folder items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that you can retrieve a folder's items and file metadata in the same request. You will need to make separate API calls to retrieve each file's metadata. Take a look at the [get all metadata endpoint](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#get-all-metadata) for more info.